# UINavigationController setViewControllers does not seem to be working for me

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am sure that this is my problem and not something with the navigationController class.  I am using a NavigationController to keep track of a stack of ViewControllers of size 2 at the most.  So when there are 1 or less I push a new VC on. When there are two I essentially, replace the stack with a stack containing the new VC and stripping out where I just was.  The code looks like:

```
- (IBAction)displayNextView:(id)sender 
{
    FBRightVC *nextVC = [[FBRightVC alloc] init];

    if ([[self.navigationController viewControllers] count] <= 1)
    {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController: nextVC 
                                             animated: YES];
        NSLog(@"iffy");
    } 
    else if ([[self.navigationController viewControllers] count] == 2)
    {
        NSMutableArray *newVCArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
                                      [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0],  nextVC, nil];
        NSLog(@"VC's in newVCArray = %i", [newVCArray count]);
        [self.navigationController setViewControllers: newVCArray animated: NO];
        NSLog(@"VC's in navigationController VC Array = %i", [self.navigationController.viewControllers count]);
        [newVCArray release];
    }
    [nextVC release];
}
```

The program seems to be behaving properly, but the output I get to the log is:

2012-01-16 16:09:46.485 SA101[7671:f803] VC's in newVCArray = 2

2012-01-16 16:09:46.486 SA101[7671:f803] VC's in navigationController VC Array = 0

So the ViewController array that I am putting in is the right size.  But the size of the array of ViewControllers reported by the navigationController itself is 0.  I am not worried about this but puzzled and curious.  The reason I am not worried is that the else statement is always executed the next time through - which means that there are in fact two VC's in the navigationControllers stack at that point.  Can someone educate me as to why the immediate inquiry returns a different result than the later inquiry to the navigationController?

[**This part answered in comments** - A possibly related question is: Should I be releasing the NSMutableArray that I am allocating to hold the new ViewController stack that I am putting in?]

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `[self.navigationController setViewControllers:newVCArray animated:NO]`?

Comment: Yes it should be.  I will correct the code.  Even with the correction the results are the same, however.

Comment: Yes to you should be releasing the NSMutableArray, the setViewControllers:animated: retains that for you

Comment: @XSlash Thanks for answering the memory management part of the question.  I have amended my code. Even with your suggestion, however, the behavior of the UINavigationController is the same.

Comment: @KrishnaK `[self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO]` and `[self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers]` are identical (cf. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621873-viewcontrollers?language=objc) 
"Assigning a new array of view controllers to this property is equivalent to calling the setViewControllers:animated: method with the animated parameter set to NO."